# Wrong format of JSON Array after a successful POST using Apex Class

Tags: apex, query, json, list, post

I've been trying to create a List from the Account object, filtered by their record type, to be sent to our website using the Apex Class. I managed to create the query correctly and it returned the organisations that I wanted, and I managed to send the result of that query to our endpoint using the below code:

```
public class WPPost {
public static HttpResponse WPPost() {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('the_endpoint');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    request.setBody(JSON.serialize(Query.findAll()));
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    System.debug(response); 
    return response;
}
```

The below is the query code itself in Apex Class.

```
public class Query {
public static List<Account> findAll(){
        List<Account> results = (List<Account>) [SELECT Id,Name,Public_Description__c,Website,ShippingCountry, FROM Account WHERE RecordTypeId='0120I000000ygO6QAI'];
return results;
}
```

Despite the POST itself being successful, the format of the result that I got in the endpoint wasn't what I expected:

```
(
[0] => [{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/0010w000005QkRNAA0"},"Id":"0010w000005QkRNAA0","Name":"Member 2","Public_Description__c":"
Lorem Ipsum Dolor si amet Numero 2

","Website":"www.membernumber2.asia","ShippingCountry":"Indonesia","RecordTypeId":"0120I000000ygO6QAI","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"},{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/0010w000005QvtqAAC"},"Id":"0010w000005QvtqAAC","Name":"Member 4","Website":"www.membernumero4.asia","ShippingCountry":"Philippines","RecordTypeId":"0120I000000ygO6QAI","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"},{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/0010w000005Qki9AAC"},"Id":"0010w000005Qki9AAC","Name":"Member 3","Public_Description__c":"
Lorem Ipsum Dolor si amet Numero 3

","Website":"www.membernumber3.asia","ShippingCountry":"Cambodia","RecordTypeId":"0120I000000ygO6QAI","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"},{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/0010w000005QkIHAA0"},"Id":"0010w000005QkIHAA0","Name":"Member 1","Public_Description__c":"
Lorem Ipsum Dolor si met Numero 1

","Website":"www.membernumber1.asia","ShippingCountry":"Singapore","RecordTypeId":"0120I000000ygO6QAI","CurrencyIsoCode":"USD"}]
)
```

I'm really unsure what else to change since I thought using JSON.serialize would help me get the format that I need, which is something like:

```
{
   "Id":"0010w000005QkIHAA0"
   "Name":"Member 1"
   "Public_Description__c":"Lorem Ipsum Dolor si met Numero 1"
   "Website":"www.membernumber1.asia"
   "ShippingCountry":"Singapore"
   "RecordTypeId":"0120I000000ygO6QAI"
}
```

I wonder if anyone can help me realise if the wrong part was my Apex code or something else...?

Comment: Can you try setting header Accept? 
     `request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');`

Comment: Are you expecting a single record? Your Apex Code is clearly returning a list of records, which you appear to be parsing in PHP. I think it would be beneficial if you described what your end goal is. Can you please [edit] your question to include more information?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is normal when serializing an SObject.

The only difference between what you're seeing, and what you want is that the serialization is including `"attributes":{...}`. This extra information helps Salesforce determine what kind of SObject you're working with (in case you ever want to deserialize back into an SObject).

It's been a while since I did any work in PHP, but I suspect the `[0] => <JSON string>` is just PHP sticking the entirety of your JSON into the `$_POST` superglobal array. PHP isn't auto-deserializing (which sounds like a terrible idea from a security standpoint), so you only have the one item in the array.

Honestly, I don't think there's anything that you really need to do here. PHP's `json_decode()` should be able to take what you have here, and you can just simply pretend that `deserialized[0]->attributes` can't be used.

If you just can't bring yourself to ignore the `attributes`, then the easiest route to go would probably be to make a simple inner class to hold your data as Strings.